# ‘3 out of 10’ on a scale in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german, numbers

I had a meeting with a German friend and he asked me for my German level. I responded with *drei von zehn*. I intended to imply a scale from 1 to 10 where my current score is 3.

How do I tell someone my level is 3 out of 10? Is *drei von zehn* correct?

It felt awkward and that it was a mistake and he didn’t want to correct me so I don’t feel bad or something.

Comment: You used one time "drei von zehn" und one time "Drei von Zehn". I changed it to make it uniform (even though I am not 100% sure if capitalized numbers are correct here).

Comment: What does 10 means? Speaking like a native?

Comment: For language levels a different scheme is widely used, see [Europäischer Referenzrahmen](http://www.europaeischer-referenzrahmen.de/sprachniveau.php).

Comment: "I rate 5 out of 7 for a perfect score!" ^^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you wish to express with that.

If you wanted to say "On a scale from one to ten, I'm on level three", then yes, "Drei von zehn" is correct.

Comment: I daresay its correct in any context.

Comment: @Kristina Except for those contexts where *drei aus zehn* (or others) is better.

Comment: @Jan Sicher? Habe ich noch nie gehört. Bei Schulnoten zum Beispiel. Ich hatte (eine) 2 aus 6?

Comment: @Kristina »Choose 3 out of 10.« → »Wähle 3 aus 10.«

Comment: @Jan Richtig. Hab ein bisschen auf dem Schlauch gestanden. ;)

Comment: @Jan: Selbst bei "Choose 3 out of 10" kenne ich nur "Wähle drei *von* zehn" oder "Wähle drei *von* zehn *aus*", außer beim Lotto, wo es um 6 aus 49 Möglichkeiten gehen.

Comment: I think this sounds really weird unless you explicitly say "auf einer Skala von ..." or at least indicate a unit ("drei von zehn Punkten").

Answer (score 7):

This *… out of ten* scale isn't popular among German speakers. It's one of the markers to spot an U.S. american (or people who watched too many U.S. sitcoms.)

Most German speakers use … % or fractions instead.

> Ich bin zu 90 Prozent von ihrer Idee überzeugt.

*I am 90 percent convinced of your idea.*

> Ich habe dich nur zur Hälfte verstanden.

*I understood only half of what you said.*

> Drei Viertel der Zeit haben wir angestanden.

*Three quarters of the time we stood in queues.*

For communicating skills (aside from grades) you should not use a scale at all but tell what your latest/best skill is, as that is far more informative. German speakers don't do so much small talk but expect information. It's not uncommon to admit insignificant/understandable weaknesses and it will make you sound totally German.

> Ich verstehe Deutsch schon sehr gut, wenn mein Geprächspartner langsam und deutlich spricht.
>
> Deutsch sprechen kann ich noch nicht so gut.

Answer (score 6):

To me, saying **only**, "*Drei von zehn*", sounds a bit strange unless it is clear from context that you are rating yourself on some scale.

If it is not clear from context, I would rather make clear what you are talking about by saying something like: "*Auf einer Skala von 1 bis 10 würde ich mir eine 3 geben.*"